# clone a project to my laptop, how to make my local one up to date

Tags: git

I have clone a project from Bitbucket to my laptop, how can I make my local version up to date if others have some commits to the project without clone it again?

Comment: Useful reading: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: you can just `git pull`